# Python translate list/dicts in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

> Sorry, I didn't really know what to put in title, I hope the example will be enough

### Case 1 - list

I have an object this format:

```
{
    'key[0]': 'value 0',
    'key[1]': 'value 1',
    'key[2]': 'value 2'
}
```

And I want to get an object like this:

```
{
    'key': [
        'value 0',
        'value 1',
        'value 2'
    ]
}
```

### Case 2 - dict

Another object I could receive is something like this:

```
{
    'key[subkey0]': 'value 0',
    'key[subkey1]': 'value 1',
    'key[subkey2]': 'value 2'
}
```

And I want to get:

```
{
    'key': {
        'subkey0': 'value 0',
        'subkey1': 'value 1',
        'subkey2': 'value 2'
    }
}
```

---

My question is, is there any lib that does that? If not, what is the most effective/optimized way to do that?

> You can consider that in the first case the list I received will be always complete, that means that no number will be skipped

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Are you sure those aren't json strings? If they are, you can use json.loads to convert them to dictionaries.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I did it already with string manipulation. But I thought that it looked too hacky. So I asked here not to know what is possible to make this work, but what is the best, considering best practices and optimization.

Comment: @leaf The objects I received are already after using `json.loads` on a json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
import pprint

def convert(d):
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    for key, value in d.items():
        main, sub = re.match(r'(\w+)\[(\w+)\]', key).groups()
        result[main][sub] = value

    result = dict(result)  # just for display really
    pprint.pprint(result)

convert({
    'key1[subkey0]': 'value 0',
    'key1[subkey1]': 'value 1',
    'key2[subkey0]': 'value 2',
    'key2[subkey1]': 'value 3',
})
```

Output:

```
{'key1': {'subkey0': 'value 0', 'subkey1': 'value 1'},
 'key2': {'subkey0': 'value 2', 'subkey1': 'value 3'}}
```

Comment: I tought regex was going to be overkill, but your code looks really clean!
This only solves the second case, but I was looking for a best practice, so I can figure the first case myself :). 
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

For the first case,

```
old = {
    'key[0]': 'value 0',
    'key[1]': 'value 1',
    'key[2]': 'value 2'
}
new = dict()
the_key = old.keys()[0].split("[")[0]
new[the_key] = list()
for key in old:
    new[the_key].append(old[key])

print new
```

Splitted one of the old dictionary keys by `[` to get the real key. Then constructed the new dict using this key. It strikes me as a bad practice, yet it works. So you can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, it looks like a bad practice, what I was looking for was a way to avoid that.